# Первичное и вторичное значение слов

Tags: значение-слов

Определите, в каких сочетаниях значения выделенных слов являются первичными, а в каких – вторичными, переносными. Укажите, какие свойства предметов и явлений обусловили возможность появления вторичных значений. В результате какого типа переноса они возникли?

1. Корень зуба, ели, зла, слова, квадратный.
2. Игла для инъекций, сосны, швейная, морского ежа, адмиралтейская.
3. Сладкие звуки, пирожки, улыбки.
4. Камень на дороге, в почках, на сердце.
5. Ковш экскаватора, для воды.
6. Каша манная, бетонная, в голове.
7. Мурлычет кошка, ручей, девушка песенку.

Comment: @elenaalisa, Предложите, пожалуйста, свой вариант ответа на данное задание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уважаемый(-ая) elenaalisa! Дам вам подсказку.Чтобы определить первичное и вторичное значение слов, достаточно заглянуть в словарь. В словарях дается сперва основное, первичное значение слова, а потом переносное значение, т.е. вторичное. Чтобы определить какие свойства и явления обусловили возможность появления вторичных значений, прочитайте о метафоре, метонимии. А потом сами сделайте это задание, а мы проверим. Можете почитать здесь: [Метафора](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=516.3_0d_IfGXK89SlskbT9QYFori1Z3MpXBoxuFpVscwMcwAojbwIf4-nQUdaOwcCVBza2ZUv135CDWjCaud9EAkegyA4YGfTej6_egfsC8E8E.80cb1d1ad1039db2a8296b2f7ffc2b95fadca138&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xulx1en6POiHSwvokIg6aHAgNQjLrfdjHUC8EhHHSZkfm5MASYf6sbi_dblTMFzVw9fNYdWQDYGrShqDRI-J-AEoj3Vm8pa4STqwg4Ssy_x2LX5swN_cD9imOa3ECYgchyh34tgnoxwSezRUq-3QLF9Wcu7nbj8QufZkofyfyPvuMI8iHAr745rS7K1RR3BSQ7qtHy7TByhbA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxb25KS2FnTFVCbGNjd1RUU2pXckpfTjZmRjVnb0FYX1FYR0VfT1dEd0JUTDVDNVdKV1NJTmJURGhQa1N6RTlLcXZuaWhhcWU5LVlVNXZuaWdhWWRPbGFIeXJrUnNwSmJkYzdqYjA2TnFFNFE&b64e=2&sign=a297ca37c972160f65f0a9266e05ec3e&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1416661528436&mc=4.311280045756846) и здесь: [Метонимия](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=516.x-2mYykEbuRubDczIYZtdeCqpdvPLzpVvuWUrkiGQUncrYlbLNl8am1CDDDvO2TqIzYZh1_v8ZtBlNwea1CKu6ZOiCbbUabk7yId-G-RBBU.4b055484b52a22ff9734f03761e89001ce86078a&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xukz0dqPN807yUm-tptTKWVeR05kt28NpPMBPHJQHwpv_5DTSwdRtFKx7ZOwnyW56gLcCGYj8ABqTP5mQ4YlPdpusx2IuL0LHSxTDIHyWKCLQ5wBDv7AjUIABX8_Cmk3o30MPhz8h3EX0ygqTaskgUFmRrlVCS5LH6ynn-DEKjom0eHjSBU3imFCWY4ksooTstBfjmQ7mx9vA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxck01b09icEh6NDRmcjZGNmVseWNaeWtoQktZQ1U3cjFOeTltZjJvNkpKZXVIZk0tYkNicXdrRGl5MDREQzdBMjZFdGN1Q3Flc2czNVBNd0Z2Snc0YkFRTmNkOG45MkQtTXpUc2NOWW82dnhLeFdRN1pPSVVBaVFwWmxZQUlGTkdkNFpZZ0dMMUxZcnNNV2VsR3BoVXAwSkg4b2RjYmMyZ1JnZjhTaDBoLXRt&b64e=2&sign=532f54395d31b76ec07ce20f9d63f7cc&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1416661655879&mc=4.338213187791001).

Comment: Абсолютно правильный ответ. )